# Как создать массив из строки PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть строка инпутов  `<input type="text" value="50000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000">`

Как создать массив из этих инпутов что бы каждый инпут был в массиве под своим номером.

Я пробовал так:

```
$tab2 = "<input type="text" value="50000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000"><br><input type="text" value="100000">";
$artab2 = explode("<br>", $tab2);
print_r($artab2)
```

Но вочему то выводит он всю строку загоняет в первый элемент `Array ( [0] =>`

Comment: Как минимум все внутренние кавычки нужно экранировать или заменить на другие.

Comment: Ну у меня в коде не строка с инпутами и кавычками, а элемент массива с этой строкой `$arResult["QUESTIONS"]["q39"]["HTML_CODE"]` а в нем подобная строка содержится и вот нужно разложить ее в массив. То есть первая операция у меня выглядит вот так `$tab2 = $arResult["QUESTIONS"]["q39"]["HTML_CODE"];` это я тут для наглядности так написал

Comment: Заменил кавычки на одинарные `$arrtb = str_replace("\"", "'", $tab2);` , результат не изменился

Comment: вообще-то, все работает https://onlinephp.io/c/aa757 вы уверены, что в строке скажем не `<br />` ?

Comment: Вы были правы, это на странице `<br>` так отображался, а в базе данных он все же `<br />` вот так отображался, только заменил и все получилось. Спасибо!